# Шаблоны кода PHP

Tags: php

интересует такой вопрос. Можно ли сделать какой-то шаблон для данного скрипта?

```
if ($result['role'] == "no_role") {
    $keyboard = [
                    "one_time" => false,
                    "buttons" => [
                [
                    ["action" => [
                    "type" => "text",
                    "label" => "Рассылка"],
                    "color" => "positive"]
                ]]];
} else {
    $keyboard = [
                    "one_time" => false,
                    "buttons" => [
                [
                    ["action" => [
                    "type" => "text",
                    "label" => "Помощь"],
                    "color" => "primary"]
                ],[
                    ["action" => [
                    "type" => "text",
                    "label" => "Информация"],
                    "color" => "primary"]
                ]]]; }

if ($result['role'] == "no_role") {
    $mk->send("Привет {$user_info->first_name}, рад тебя видеть.\n".
              "Список доступных команд:\n\n".
              "→ «Рассылка постов»\n".
              "→ «Помощь»\n", $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token);
} else {
    $mk->send("Привет {$user_info->first_name}, рад тебя видеть.\n".
              "Список доступных команд:\n\n".
              "→ «Рассылка постов»\n".
              "→ «Помощь»\n".
              "→ «TOOLS»", $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token); }
```

Так как данный код появляется N количество раз, хотелось бы его вынести и использовать по необходимости.

Comment: вынести кусок в файл и потом `include` в нужном месте не подходит?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, подходит, но думал можно это реализовать не делая новых файлов...

Comment: Так сложно что-то предметно подсказать, на зная архитектуры вашего приложения. Можно создать класс вроде RolesManager и ему поручить все эти действия. Вообще, сам этот кусок кода уже дублирует один и тот же условный оператор, что не очень хорошо.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, могли бы подсказать как лучше сделать? Что бы не было условного дублирования?

Comment: Можно. Моя любимая шпаргалка: https://tproger.ru/translations/design-patterns-simple-words-1/amp/

Comment: В чем проблема? Создай класс с методом и в местах где тебе нужно вывести этот код обращайся к нему. Если я правильно понял вопрос)

Comment: Зачем писать ответ в вопросе? Напиши нормальный ответ и поставь у него галочку.

Comment: @u_mulder, немного затупил...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если конкретно по приведенному участку кода, то:

1. Избавиться от дублирования проверки условия. В одном месте проверяем и делаем все что нужно.
2. В таком виде, как у вас, понять структуру массива - весьма непросто. Уверен, вы сами через месяц будете ломать голову, что где лежит.
   В итоге переписать можно так:

```
// формируем начальный массив с общими значениями
$keyboard = [
    "one_time" => false,
    "buttons" => [
        [
            [
                "action" => [
                    "type" => "text"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

// сообщение
$msg = "Привет {$user_info->first_name}, рад тебя видеть.\n".
            "Список доступных команд:\n\n".
            "→ «Рассылка постов»\n".
            "→ «Помощь»\n";

// теперь один раз проверяем роль и дописываем массивы
if ($result['role'] == "no_role") {
    $keyboard['buttons'][0][0]['action']['label'] = "Рассылка";
    $keyboard['buttons'][0][0]['color'] = "positive";
} else {
    $keyboard['buttons'][0][0]['action']['label'] = "Помощь";
    $keyboard['buttons'][0][0]['color'] = "primary";
    $keyboard['buttons'][] = [
        [
            "action" => [
                "type" => "text",
                "label" => "Информация"
            ],
            "color" => "primary"
        ]
    ];
    $msg .= "→ «TOOLS»";    // здесь также дописываем сообщение
}

$mk->send($msg, $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token);
```

По поводу того, как этот участок кода использовать многократно. Все зависит от вашей архитектуры. Если вы по каким-то причинам не хотите выносить код в отдельный файл или создавать класс/классы, отвечающие за создание кнопок, то сделайте на этой же странице функцию, передавайте ей `$result['role']` и `$mk`. Ну и вызывайте там, где нужно сколько хотите раз.

UPD. один из примеров организации кода:

```
<?php

//Для работы с клавиатурой создаем класс Keyboard
class Keyboard
{
    private $keyboard;
    
    // при создании объекта укажем ему runtime
    public function __construct($runtime)
    {
        $this->keyboard = array ('one_time' => $runtime, 'buttons' => array());
    }
    
    public function addButton($label, $color, $lvl)
    {
        $button = [
            "action" => [
                "type" => "text",
                "label" => $label
            ],
            "color" => $color
        ];
        $this->keyboard['buttons'][$lvl][] = $button;
    }
    
    public function getKeyboard()
    {
        return $this->keyboard;
    }
}

// Теперь где-то в коде нужны кнопки
// Создаем объект Keyboard
$oKeyboard = new Keyboard(false);

// в зависимости от роли добавляем кнопки:
if ($result['role'] == "no_role") {
    $oKeyboard->addButton("Рассылка", "positive", 0);
} else {
    $oKeyboard->addButton("Помощь", "primary", 0);
    $oKeyboard->addButton("Информация", "positive", 0);
    $oKeyboard->addButton("Help", "negative", 1);
    $oKeyboard->addButton("Gun", "positive", 1);
    $oKeyboard->addButton("World", "negative", 2);
}
// выводим массив с кнопками
$keyboard = $oKeyboard->getKeyboard();
echo '<pre>'.print_r($keyboard, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Расскажите пожалуйста по подробнее, как работает `$keyboard` у вас в примере? Вы его вынесли в `if` при этом сохранив работоспособность, не понимаю принцип работы но очень хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: В начале просто создал `$keyboard` массив, а затем, в условии, добавил в него данные, либо одни, либо другие, в зависимости от условия. Там же в условии не создается новая переменная `$keyboard`. Просто в уже существующий массив добавляются ключи и значения.

Comment: С этим разобрался. А если мне нужно создавать произвольное количество строк и кнопок в них. Как это лучше сделать? Была идея сначала делается каркас, а потом просто добавляются значения. Но как-то не особо получается

Comment: @ТимофейКучербаев я дописал ответ, посмотрите, может, так вам будет удобнее. Если не хочется заморачиваться с объектами, то просто сделайте функцию, передавайте ей то, что меняется  и пусть она врзвращает массив с кнопкой. И уже его добавляйте в общему массиву кнопок.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @ТимофейКучербаев не за что, надеюсь, удалось помочь как-то )

Comment: Я немного изменил вашу функцию (добавил в свой ответ). Разумно использовать `$i` для ограничения строк?

Comment: Простите за навязчивость, но повторюсь: настоятельно не рекомендую укорачивать код и делать его нечитабельным при этом, потом сами не разберетесь. Есть же стандарты, PSR4, не зря люди старались. По вопросу: не понимаю, что вы хотите функцией buttonMore и как она должна ограничивать. Вы хотите в функции дописать проверку, неб ольше ли $i какого-то значения?

Comment: Обязательно почитаю про стандарт PSR4, дописал в своём ответе. `$i` играет роль идентификатора  строки (значение определяет в какой строке что будет). Ещё раз большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: сейчас допишу ответ, а по коду - дело в том, что беглый взгляд на вашу конструкцию после `$button = [` дает такое представление: в массиве `$button ` четыре элемента. А оказывается, что там еще подмассив есть. Это, конечно, сейчас более-менее понятно, но все равно - приходится именно вникать, что к чему, хотя должно быть сразу видно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110432/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
class Keyboard {
    private $keyboard;
    public function __construct($runtime) {
        $this->keyboard = array ('one_time' => $runtime, 'buttons' => array());
    }
    
    public function ButtonMore($label, $color, $i) {
        $button = [
            "action" => [
            "type" => "text",
            "label" => $label],
            "color" => $color];
        $this->keyboard['buttons'][$i][] = $button; }
    
    public function ButtonOne($label, $color) {
        $button = [
            "action" => [
            "type" => "text",
            "label" => $label],
            "color" => $color];
        $this->keyboard['buttons'][][] = $button; }
    
    public function getKeyboard () {
        return $this->keyboard; } }

$oKeyboard = new Keyboard(false);

if ($result['role'] == "no_role") {
    $oKeyboard->ButtonMore("Рассылка", "positive");
} else {
    $oKeyboard->ButtonMore("Помощь", "primary", 0);
    $oKeyboard->ButtonMore("Информация", "positive", 0);
    $oKeyboard->ButtonMore("Help", "negative", 1);
    $oKeyboard->ButtonMore("Gun", "positive", 1);
    $oKeyboard->ButtonOne("World", "negative");
}
$keyboard = $oKeyboard->getKeyboard();
```

На выходе получаем кнопки в таком расположении:

```
Помощь | Информация
Help | Gun
World
```